# GitHub GraphQL API Problems parsing JSON

Tags: python, python-requests, github-api, graphql

What is wrong here?

```
query='{ repositoryOwner(login : "ALEXSSS") { login repositories (first : 30){ edges { node { name } } } } }'

headers = {'Authorization': 'token xxx'}

r2=requests.post('https://api.github.com/graphql', '{"query": \"'+query+'\"}',headers=headers)

print (r2.json())
```

I've got

```
{'message': 'Problems parsing JSON', 'documentation_url': 'https://developer.github.com/v3'}
```

but this snippet of code below works correctly

```
query1= '''{ viewer { login name } }'''  

headers = {'Authorization': 'token xxx'} 

r2=requests.post('https://api.github.com/graphql', '{"query": \"'+query1+'\"}',headers=headers) 

print (r2.json())
```

I've tried out to change quotes (from " into ' or with " and so on)  but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is related with the double quotes (").
On the first snippet, when you join the `'{"query": \"'+query+'\"}'` with the query variable, you get the following result:

```
{"query": "{ repositoryOwner(login : "ALEXSSS") { login repositories (first : 30){ edges { node { name } } } } }"}
```

Notice how the double quote from `"ALEXSSS"` are not escaped, therefore the resultant string is not a json valid format.

When you run the second snippet, the resultant string is:

```
{"query": "{ viewer { login name } }"}
```

which is a valid json string.

The easiest and best solution is simply use the JSON library instead of trying to do it manually, so you won't need to worry about escaping characters.

```
import json

query='{ repositoryOwner(login : "ALEXSSS") { login repositories (first : 30){ edges { node { name } } } } }'
headers = {'Authorization': 'token xxx'}

r2=requests.post('https://api.github.com/graphql', json.dumps({"query": query}), headers=headers)

print (r2.json())
```

But remember that you could also just escape the characters on the query manually:

```
query='{ repositoryOwner(login : \"ALEXSSS\") { login repositories (first : 30){ edges { node { name } } } } }'
headers = {'Authorization': 'token xxx'}

r2=requests.post('https://api.github.com/graphql', '{"query": "'+query1+'"}', headers=headers)

print (r2.json())
```

it works as expected :)

Comment: why then the second code snippet work correctly in my example?

Comment: Updated the original answer to include the explanation.

Comment: @AdrianoMartins can please have a look at this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063825/how-to-access-the-github-graphql-api-from-java-without-running-curl-commands-ins]