# How to compose requests for communication between Java back-end and 3rd party GraphQL API?

Tags: api, java-8, graphql, integration

I am trying to integrate (create flawless data-communication) my Java-based back-end and 3rd party GraphQL API.

I have found similar question that partially answers mine. [How to access the GitHub GraphQL API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063825/how-to-access-the-github-graphql-api-from-java-without-running-curl-commands-ins?r=SearchResults)

All requests I searched on the search engine or snippets I found on Github are related to how to create GraphQL API on the server side, so my Back-end will have GraphQL wrapper/endpoint. That is not the case for me.

The question is the following, if there are any wrappers, annotations that I can use that simplify creature of `query`s and `mutation`s from the POJOs. The reason why I want it, instead of creation hard-coded strings my objects can be dynamic and include, exclude fields. I need any examples for both mutations and queries. Naturally, I don't want to create a lot of custom resolvers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have not found any answer or library with significant enough documentation during the time of writing code. I created my own wrapper for wrapping POJO into `mutation` and `query`.

This implementation may not work for all GraphQL APIs. Therefore, the important note is that this implementation was created specifically for `Xledger` integration.

**Main wrapper**

```
public String simpleResolver(String operationName, String requestName, Map<String, Object> requestedParams, List<String> requestedFields, String objectNestingStructure) {
        String params = nvl(requestedParams).entrySet().stream().map(p -> p.getKey() + ":" + wrapWithQuotes(p.getValue())).collect(joining(","));

        String[] obejctNesting = nvl(objectNestingStructure).split("\\.");
        String fields = nvl(requestedFields).stream().collect(joining("\n"));
        return "{ \"query\":\"" + operationName + "{\n"  + requestName + "(" + params + ") {\n" + buildObjectNestingStructure(obejctNesting, fields) + "}\n}\n\"," +
               "\"variables\":" + null + "," +
               "\"operationName\":" + null + "}";
    }
```

**Parser and wrapper for nested GraphQL-like structure**

```
public String buildObjectNestingStructure(String[] objectNestingStructure, String fields) {
    StringBuilder objectHead = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder objectTail = new StringBuilder();

    for (String objectNesting : objectNestingStructure) {
        objectHead.append(objectNesting);
        objectHead.append(" {\n");

        objectTail.append("\n}");
    }
    objectHead.append(fields);
    objectHead.append(objectTail);

    return objectHead.toString();
}
```

**POJO wrapper to requestParams**

```
public <T> Map<String, Object> getParams(T entity) {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    Class<?> cls = entity.getClass();
    for (Field field : cls.getDeclaredFields()) {
        try {
            String fieldName = field.getName();
            Object fieldValue = field.get(entity);
            if (fieldValue != null) {
                params.put(fieldName, fieldValue);
            }
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return params;
}
```

This solution works for both `query` and `mutation`, since both of them have `param` and in my case, I always took, at least, `dbId` field.

Also `nvl` is utility function for substituting `null` objects with default value.